# Elasticsearch - compound index or discrete indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 6.3 (but our ES experience is all from earlier versions)

We have a typical multi tenant cloud app. 5,000 accounts on the cloud app. Each account has 500 to 1,000,000 records/documents.

When we use a single monolithic Elasticsearch index, it is ~800GB in size, and our queries are slow to run -- really slow. Like 5-14 seconds with the data on a hot SSD based server. (We are doing sorts on different columns, and of course only ever want data for a single accountid.)

We know that the data for a single account would give us super fast ES queries, but partitioning into 5,000 indexes seems over the top, and might require a rather large cluster so that no single server has to handle 1,000 indexes.

In my SQL thinking, I keep wanting to make the big monolithic index have a "compound index" aspect (like the accountid), since every query has an accountid prefix, but I am not sure ES can handle this.

How do we find a path forward?

Comment: How many data nodes/primary/replica shards do you have for your current single index?

Comment: You might try creating an index with some absurd number of shards, then use document routing (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) to assign all of the documents for each account to its own dedicated shard. Any queries that hit the entire index would perform terribly, but queries that were directed to a single shard would run more quickly. You'd also run into hotspot problems if one account had a disproportionate number of documents or volume of searches.

Comment: @Vincent We have been testing a single box, 5 shard config so far. It gives performance so week we know we need a different approach.

Comment: @JasonRosendale Thanks!  Wouldn't bucket aggregations also do the trick?